# Is there a general theorem which states - as we raise power of an integer, what happens to its remainders?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Perfect squares can not have a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$.

Similarly, perfect cubes can not have remainders of $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, and $7$ when divided by $9$.

> Is there a general theorem which states - as we raise power of an integer, what happens to its remainders?

Thank you for leads/hints/references/answers.

This is just out of curiosity.  No home work for any body.  The first statement can be proved easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with Fermat's Little Theorem: If $p$ is prime and $p \nmid a$, then $a^{p-1}$ has remainder 1 when divided by $p$. On the other hand, if $p \mid a$, then $p \mid a^{p-1}$ also, so $a^{p-1}$ has remainder 0 when divided by $p$. So for a prime $p$, the only possible remainders when a $(p-1)$-st power is divided by $p$ are 0 and 1.

Next, if $r$ is a multiple of $p-1$ for some prime $p$, then any $r$-th power is necessarily a $(p-1)$-st power, so you can again conclude that the only possible remainders on division by $p$ are 0 and 1. You may be able to get several restrictions this way—for example, 4 is divisible by both $3-1$ and $5-1$, so the remainders of fourth powers can only be 0 or 1 when divided by either 3 or 5. If you do get several such restrictions, you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine them into yet another restriction. In this example, knowing the remainders on division by 3 and 5 tells you the possible remainders on division by 15:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{Remainder when divided by}\ldots & 3 & 5 & 15 \\ \hline
& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& 0 & 1 & 6 \\
& 1 & 0 & 10 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
$$

So far I've started by fixing the power and asking if there are particular divisors for which we can say something about the remainders. If you want to go the other way—start with the divisor, and ask for which powers we can say something about the remainders—it is useful to consider Euler's Theorem, which generalizes Fermat's Little Theorem: If $m \geq 2$ and $\gcd(a, m) = 1$, then $a^{\phi(m)}$ has remainder 1 when divided by $m$. Here $\phi(m)$ is the Euler's totient function, which counts the number of positive integers up to $m$ which are relatively prime to $m$. For example, $\phi(9) = 6$, since there are 6 positive integers (1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8) up to 9 that are relatively prime to 9. We could then say that if $\gcd(a, 9) = 1$, then $a^6$ has remainder 1 when divided by 9.